# When should I use the error handling middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

What is the advantage of catching errors and responding from within a middleware function like in example A.

**Example A**

```
function(req, res, next)
{
    if (err) {
      err.message = 'Not Found';
      res.status(404).json(err);
      return;
    }
}
```

Versus passing the error to the error handling middleware like in example B.

**Example B**

```
function(req, res, next)
{
    if (err) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    }
}
```

error handling middleware:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({message: "error"});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are piping the request through several functions to process it, and the error in one of the first functions is superficial. You can still process the request, but you need to send a warning or handle the error afterwards. Perhaps you want to gather all of the errors in the pipeline report them back. Example B allows this.

But imagine the error is critical, and you know you won't be able to proceed. In that case you, can't call next, because the next function won't know how to deal with a fundamentally broken request. Here is where example A comes in handy.